# Spring Boot Search Data by Date (formated in ZonedDateTime)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-filter

I want to get list of forms submitted on a particular date. Date will be passed by Admin in Search box (from front end it will be String but in Back end it's `ZonedDateTime`).

I've written method in Repository as:

```
List<AdmissionForm> findByDateContains(ZonedDateTime datePart);
```

method formation ref : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-from-method-names/

My Service class background logic is like:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<AdmissionFormDTO> findByDate(ZonedDateTime datepart){
    return admissionFormRepository.findByDateContains(datepart).stream()
        .map(admissionFormMapper::toDto)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And My Resource endpoint is like:

```
@GetMapping("/admissionForms/date")
@Timed
public List<AdmissionFormDTO> findByDate(@RequestParam("date") String date){
    log.debug("REST request to get AdmissionForms by searchTerm :" + date);
    //String to ZonedDateTime method conversion from seperate class
    ZonedDateTime zDate = SupportUtils.convertStringDateToZoneDateTime(date);
    return admissionFormService.findByDate(zDate);
}
```

I've tried with String search terms and it's working fine but got only trouble with Searching with Date.

I got the exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%2018-11-20T00:00Z%] did not match expected type [java.time.ZonedDateTime (n/a)]' and exception = 'Parameter value [%2018-11-20T00:00Z%] did not match expected type [java.time.ZonedDateTime (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%2018-11-20T00:00Z%] did not match expected type [java.time.ZonedDateTime (n/a)]'
```

Give some corrections so I can do search by Date as expected.

***EDITED:***
I changed datatype from `ZoneDateTime` to `LocalDate` and solve accordingly as below (Skip timing for now):

My Repository code:

```
List<AdmissionForm> findByDate(LocalDate datePart);
```

My Service Class:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<AdmissionFormDTO> findByDate(String datepart){
    LocalDate localDatePart = SupportUtils.convertStringDateToLocalDate(datepart);
    return admissionFormRepository.findByDate(localDatePart).stream()
        .map(admissionFormMapper::toDto)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My Resource Entry Point:

```
@GetMapping("/admissionForms/date")
@Timed
public List<AdmissionFormDTO> findByDate(@RequestParam("date")String date){
    log.debug("REST request to get AdmissionForms by searchTerm :{}",date);
    return admissionFormService.findByDate(date);
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions, but can't find a way to work with `ZondDateTime` so we change requirements little bit. Hope others will get help from question and suggested answers here.

Comment: can you share the uri which you are trying to hit ?

Comment: it's in my local server not available outside. Can't help with that one :(

Comment: i have suggested one answer. Might help you to fix this issue can you check?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTimeFormat`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) annotation which by default handles the ISO `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` date time format:

```
public List<AdmissionFormDTO> findByDate(
          @RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat ZonedDateTime date) {
  return admissionFormService.findByDate(date);
}
```

You should further customize `@DateTimeFormat` if your date doesn't contain seconds fields as in your example.